# Prove that it exists $i \neq j$ s.t. $P(A_i \cap A_j) \geq \frac{nc^2-c}{n-1}$ with $P(A_i) \geq c $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

#### Question:

Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n \subset \Omega $ a sequence of outcome such that $P(A_i) \geq c $ for all $i$.
Prove that it exists $i \neq j$ s.t. $P(A_i \cap A_j) \geq \frac{nc^2-c}{n-1}$

I have tried different ways including the following one but I did not succeed to conclude.

1-First note that: $\int (\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} I_{A_i})^2dP= \sum_{i \neq j} \int I_{A_i}I_{A_j}dP + \sum_{i = j} \int I_{A_i}^2dP= \sum_{i \neq j} P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{i = j}P(A_i)$

2-Now we know that $\sum_{i = j}P(A_i)$ is the sum of $n$ element, thus $\sum_{i = j}P(A_i) \geq nc$

3-We know too that $\sum_{i \neq j} P(A_i \cap A_j)$ is the sum of $n(n-1)$ elements.
More over $\forall i \neq j$ by absurd let suppose that $P(A_i \cap A_j) < \frac{nc^2-c}{n-1}$.
But after I don't succeed to continue. Can someone help me please?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful.  I think $P(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n) \geq \sum_i P(A_i) - \sum_{i< j} P(A_i)$.  Let $m = \max_{i\neq j} P(A_i\cap A_j)$. So, $1\geq\sum_i P(A_i) - \sum_{i< j} P(A_i)\geq cn - m(n-1)n/2$ which implies $m\geq 2(cn-1)/(n(n-1))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Remark: $z = \sum_{i = j}P(A_i)$*

4-Let define $X = \sum_i I_{A_i} $ so according to the Jensen inequality we have that $(E[X])^2 \leq E[X^2]$ or equivalently $(E[X])^2 = (\int \sum_i I_{A_i} dP)^2 = ( \sum_i P(A_i))^2 = z^2 \leq E[X^2] = \int (\sum_i I_{A_i} )^2 dP   $.

5-Remind that by absurd assumption we have that: $ (E[X])^2= \sum_{i \neq j} P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{i = j}P(A_i) < n(n-1) \frac{nc^2-c}{n-1} + \sum_{i = j}P(A_i) = nc(nc-1) + \sum_{i = j}P(A_i) = z + nc(nc-1)$

6- From "-5" and "-4" combine we get that $z^2 < z + nc(nc-1) \Rightarrow z^2 - z = z(z-1) < nc(nc-1) $.
On an other side $z^2 - z$ is an increasing function on $z \geq 1$ and $nc \geq 1$ (other wise it is negative and the given inequality is satisfied). And let remember that $z=\sum_{i = j}P(A_i)$ with $ \forall i $ we have that  $P(A_i) \geq c \Rightarrow z \geq nc $. So We should have $z(z-1) \geq nc(nc-1)$ and not $z(z-1) < nc(nc-1)$.

Q.E.D.

Comment: I like it! It is also a simple proof for $$\sum P(A_i) \ge s \Rightarrow \sum_{i< j} P(A_i\cap A_j) \ge \binom{s}{2}.$$

Comment: @Amir Thank. i do not know this inequality.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

It is enough to show the following fact: if $\sum P(A_i) \ge s$, then $\sum_{i< j} P(A_i\cap A_j) \ge \binom{s}{2}$ as follows.  Consider the polytope formed by all possible values $(\sum P(A_i), \sum P(A_i \cap A_j)$. It is the image under a linear map of a $2^n-1$ dimensional simplex  consisting of all the possible $(P(A_1^{\epsilon_1} \cap A_2^{\epsilon_2} \cap \ldots A_n^{\epsilon_n}))$, where $\epsilon_k = \pm 1$, $A_k^1 = A_k$, $A_k^{-1} = A_k^c$ ( the complement). The vertices of the simplex ( $2^n$ of them) correspond to the $A_i$ being $\emptyset$ or $\Omega$ ( the total set). The vertices map to $(k, \binom{k}{2})$, where $k \in \{0,1, \ldots,n\}$ (meaning $k$ of the $A_i$ are $\Omega$, the other $\emptyset$). We conclude: the set of possible values of $(\sum P(A_i), \sum P(A_i \cap A_j)$ is the convex hull of $(k, \binom{k}{2})$, with $0 \le k \le n$. Notice that these points form a convex polygon with $n+1$ vertices, inscribed in the parabola $(x, \binom{x}{2})_{x\ge 0}$. Now  the inequality follows.

Comment: Thank for your time I am going to read your answer carefully when I ll be able to

Comment: Nice proof! Could you let me know why all the possible values of $P(A_1^{\epsilon_1} \cap A_2^{\epsilon_2} \cap \ldots A_n^{\epsilon_n})$, with $\epsilon_k = \pm 1$, $A_k^1 = A_k$, $A_k^{-1} = A_k^c$, form a simplex (it is evident that the set is a subset of a simplex)? More specifically, could you provide the events $A_1, \cdots, A_n$ that generet each point $(x_1,\cdots,x_{2^n})$ of the simplex?

Comment: @Amir:Given $A_1$, $\ldots$, $A_n$ subsets of $\Omega$,  the sets $A_1^{\epsilon_1} \cap \cdots \cap A_n^{\epsilon_n}$ form a partition of $\Omega$. So the sum of their probabilities is $1$. Conversely, given $2^n$ numbers of sum $1$, take  a partition of $\Omega$ into $2^n$ subsets of the above measure. Notice that $A_1= \cup ( A_1 \cap A_2^{\epsilon_2} \cap \cdots \cap A_n^{\epsilon_n}$ )  ( a union of $2^{n-1}$ of these parts, $A_1\cap A_2$ is a union of $2^{n-2}$ of these parts. ( given $n$ subsets, we get $2^n$ parts of the total set $\Omega$ that they create( think of the Venn diagram).

Comment: Thanks! I see how the probabilities $P(A_i), P(A _i \cap A_j), \dots $ can be obtained, but I am struggling to construct events $A_1, \cdots, A_n$ such that they consistently generate all the probabilities. Could you derive the events for $\Omega=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure for a given point $(x_1,\cdots,x_{2^n})$ of the simplex. Moreover, I think the set is not a simplex for any probability spaces, while it is a subset of it. Under which conditions on the probability space, does the set become a simplex?

Comment: @Amir: Say $n=3$, and take $2^3=8$ positive numbers summing up to $1$. Partition the segment $[0,1]$ into $8$ segments of these lengths Note that we have a labelling of the segments with sequences $(\pm1, \pm  1, \pm 1)$ Now form the $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$.

Comment: @orangeskid i did not learn what is a polytope.

Comment: @orangeskid hello thank for the time you ve used to help me find an answer but i did not understand your answer. I ve written an other answer i will  be happy to have your feedback on it.

Comment: @Amir  Hello thank for your comment. I ve written an other answer i will  be happy to have your feedback on it.

Comment: @OffHakhol sure

Comment: @OffHakhol:  polytope= polyèdre.  I will look at the answer. The polytope idea gives the optimal bound for $\sum P(A_i\cap A_j)$ The estimate with $\binom{s}{2}$ is optimal only for integral $s$. The polytopes method shows with same effort that $\sum P(A_i\cap A_j \cap A_k) \ge \binom{s}{3}$, $\&$c, so it is  powerful.

Comment: What do mean by "is optimal only for integral $s$"? I think the lower bound $\frac{s(s-1)}{2}$ is tight for any $s$.

Comment: @Amir: An example: say $\sum P(A_i) = 7/2 = \frac{3+4}{2}$. Then the best lower bound for $\sum P(A_i \cap A_j)$ is in fact $\frac{\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2}}{2}$, larger than $\binom{3.5}{2}$. So the lower bound is a piecewise linear function of $s$.