Show that $ \mu(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap\dots \cap A_{i_k})>c^k-\epsilon $
Let $((0,1], \mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\{A_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ be a sequence of Borel measurable sets so that $\mu(A_i)\ge c$ for all $i\ge 1$ and some universal constants $c\in (0,1)$. Show that for all $k=1,2,3,\dots$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists $i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k$ so that
$$
\mu(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap\dots \cap A_{i_k})>c^k-\epsilon
$$

I am stuck on this question. I try to upper bound
$$
(\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i))^k
$$
for some $n\ge 1$...
I also try to specific case $k=2$: to show that
$$
\mu(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2})>c^2-\epsilon
$$
We have
$$
\mu((A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2})^c)=\mu(A_{i_1}^c\cup A_{i_2}^c)\le \mu(A_{i_1}^c)+\mu(A_{i_2}^c)\le 2(1-c)
$$
So
$$
\mu(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2})\ge 1-2(1-c)=2c-1
$$

Are you perhaps missing some assumptions? What happens if $A_i\equiv A$ and $\mu(A)=c$?

@Keen-ameteur $c^{k}-\epsilon < c^{k} \le c$.

@geetha290krm  Yeah, you're right. I misunderstood the question and jumped to comment.

Is $\mu$ maybe a finite measure? Otherwise, what happens if the $A_i$ are all pairwise disjoint?

@PhoemueX Yes, $\mu$ should be finite because $\mu([0,1])=1$ and any subset $\mu(A)\le 1$ for $A\subset [0,1]$.

@H.YDuan: This is clearly false if you have a family of disjoint sets.

@AugustoSantos But you can't have such a countable disjoint family in a finite measure space.

@User: Unbelievable. I missed that. Thanks.

For $k=2$, the same problem is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4862895/1231520

The proof is very neat and rather elementary. I will only write the details for the special case $k=2$.
For this to work, we assume that $\mu(X)=1$, which, besides, is the OP's assumption.
Noticing that $\mu(A_i)=\int \mathbb{1}_{A_i} \ d\mu$ we have that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$ (n\cdot c)^2 \leq \left( \int \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{A_i} \ d\mu \right)^2 \leq \int \left(  \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{A_i} \right)^2 d\mu, $$
by assumption and an application of Cauchy-Schwarz. Then, expanding the square we have that
$$ (n\cdot c)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i) + 2\sum_{1\leq i< j \leq n} \mu(A_i \cap A_j).$$
Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and assume for contradiction that $\mu(A_i \cap A_j) \leq \alpha \cdot c^2$, for all $i<j$. (Note that I simply rewrote the condition in an equivalent form which is slightly more convenient to work with).
Then, we must have that
$$ (n \cdot c)^2 \leq n +  n(n-1) \cdot \alpha \cdot c^2, $$
which implies that
$$ c^2 - \frac{1-c^2}{n-1}=\frac{(n \cdot c)^2 - n }{n^2-n}  \leq \alpha \cdot c^2,$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, which yields a contradiction if $n$ is chosen large enough.
An analogous argument starting from $(n\cdot c)^k \leq \left( \int \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{A_i}\ d\mu \right)^k$ and using Cauchy-Schwarz once again works for the general case too.

Just to nickpick: you actually need to assume $\mu(X) \leq 1$ for this to work, not just that $\mu(X)$ is finite.
